# Spin up AWS host with specific EBS volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I'm looking to spin up a new Amazon EC2 instance with a specific EBS volume. I see that currently you can spin up a new host with a `SnapshotId` which would create a NEW EBS volume based upon the snapshot, but because of how we are managing our EBS volumes, it would be ideal if I could use the already existing EBS volume.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [attach an existing EBS volume to an instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-attaching-volume.html) within the same availability zone. You can only attach an EBS volume to one instance at a time.

Comment: But can you spin up an instance with an EBS volume that has already been created attached to a device on it? Need to know because I'm using puppet for configuration management, and want the EBS to be attached as it spins up so the correct files are on it, rather than having to unmount it and attach the EBS volume later.

Comment: Yes, you can attach a previously created EBS volume (that is currently unattached) to an instance after you create it. You can specify the device name, then in puppet you can format it (if necessary) and mount the device after boot.